# ifの使い方について

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
　　int i;

　　if(argc <= 1)
　　　　return 1;
　　if(strcmp(argv[1], "enum") == 0)
　　　　for(i = 0;i<argc;i++)
　　　　　　printf("argv[%d] : %s\n" , i, argv[i]);
　　else if(strcmp(argv[1], "count") == 0)
　　　　printf("コマンドライン引数の数 : %d\n", argc-1);
　　return 0;
}
```

[Cの絵本 第2版]より、ifの後にelse ifではなくifを記述してありました。また2番目のifの次はelseではなく、esle ifが記述されており、それぞれ何故なのか。
実行結果が
`>` cmdparam.exe enum orange apple
argv[0] : cmdparam.exe
argv[1] : enum
argv[2] : orange
argv[3] : apple
`>`cmdparam.exe count orange apple
コマンドライン引数の数 : 3
となっております。
`>`の行はキーボードから入力した文字とのことですが、
・何処に入力した文字なのか
・何故argv[1]のenumがcountに変えているのか
以上お願い致します。

Comment: コマンドラインからの実行と言う意味が分かるでしょうか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

元質問のコードをifの実行範囲をはっきりさせるためにカッコで囲みました。
これで理解できるでしょうか？

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
　　int i;

　　if(argc <= 1){
　　　　return 1;
    }

　　if(strcmp(argv[1], "enum") == 0){
　　　　for(i = 0;i<argc;i++)
　　　　　　printf("argv[%d] : %s\n" , i, argv[i]);
　　}else{ 
        if(strcmp(argv[1], "count") == 0){
　　　　    printf("コマンドライン引数の数 : %d\n", argc-1);
        }
    }

　　return 0;
}
```

このプログラムがなにをするプログラムなのかを理解できれば、以降のあなたの疑問も理解できると思います

Comment: 基本的な文法という視点以前に、コマンドラインからの実行という視点が抜けている気がします。

Comment: コマンドラインへの入力だと気づいていなかったのでパニックになっていたようです。